# Android WhatsApp style floating header view

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

If you are familiar with WhatsApp, when you start scrolling, a view with the message's date slides down from the top of the screen. I'm trying to achieve something like that, my view is the top most view with decreased alpha and blue background, just below the ActionBar.

I did not use a ListView, below the ActionBar I have a ScrollView, and inside that ScrollView I have a LinearLayout.

I add my messages to this LinearLayout.

I could not figure a way out how to know if the date changed and need to refresh my header view.

I tried to get their positions on the screen with the

activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener() but this doesn't get triggered if you scroll fast.

Setting an onTouchListener to the ScrollView didn't work either, as the scroll may continue after I release the touch event.

It's been a long week and I'm out of ideas.

I'm open to any suggestions, thank you.

[image]

Comment: did you found a solution to this?. how were you able to differentiate dates e.g 25 june, 22 july.  i have saved them in sqlite in miliseconds format and am trying to populate my listview like your image above but how i will differentiate dates, is giving me hard time.

Comment: Hi. It's been a very long time since I've done this. But if I remember correctly, I was listening to scrolling events on the ListView, and when the top-most object is a date object, I was changing the floating date layout's date. It was working fine.

Comment: i ended up using an external library

Comment: @gikarasojokinene : did you get any

Comment: @VV yah  stickylistview https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score -1):

You can look at the [Standout](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) Library , you can handle floating windows with it.

You can also create a semi transparent activity / dialog.

Comment: Thank you David. StandOut library looks really good.

But my problem is not ceating a floating window. I already created the floating date layout, which is on the top and has a decreased alpha.

I need to understand if I've come across another date layout (that's gravity to left) so that I can change the date on the floating date layout, just like WhatsApp does.